# Javascript apply round number to an other value

Tags: javascript

I got let down by a developer and I have a very basic question that hopefully you will be able to answer.

[image]

As you can see on the image the value for "Cashflow annuel" is not rounded and what I understand from the script that I currently have is is that the function that I need to use is this one : cash = cash.toFixed(1);

However I have no idea how to apply this to the result "Cashflow annuel".

I know this is probably very basic but I have absolutly no skills for coding..

Here is the full script so you can see what I'm talking about :

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#cashflow').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                loyer_mensuel: "required",
                charges_rec: "required",
                mensualites: "required",
                charges_copro: "required",
                taxe_fonc: "required",
                autres_charges: "required"
            },
           debug: true,
            messages: {
                loyer_mensuel: "Champ obligatoire",
                charges_rec: "Champ obligatoire",
                mensualites: "Champ obligatoire",
                charges_copro: "Champ obligatoire",
                taxe_fonc: "Champ obligatoire",
                autres_charges: "Champ obligatoire"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { 
                event.preventDefault();
                loyer_mensuel = Number($("#loyer_mensuel").val());
                charges_recup = Number($("#charges_rec").val());
                mensualites = Number($("#mensualites").val());
                charges_copro = Number($("#charges_copro").val());
                taxe_fonciere = Number($("#taxe_fonc").val());
                autres_charges = Number($("#autres_charges").val());
                cash = (loyer_mensuel + charges_recup) - (mensualites + charges_copro + (taxe_fonciere/12) + autres_charges );
cash = cash.toFixed(1);
                jQuery('#cashflow-mensuel').val(cash + ' € / mois');
                jQuery('#cashflow-annuel').val(cash*12 + ' € / an');

            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Be careful that "Cashflow mensuel" is not rounded. It seems to be rounded because the final result has only one decimal unlike the "Cashflow annuel"

Answer (score 2):

Using [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) will do the trick.

```
jQuery('#cashflow-annuel').val(Math.round(cash*12) + ' € / an');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer proposed by @FabienGreard is correct but it could be interesting for you to have multiple options

## [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/round)

This function will round your number to the nearest whole number thus you will never have a decimal number

```
jQuery('#cashflow-annuel').val(Math.round(cash*12) + ' € / an');
//Output ==> -6766
```

if you want to round it with decimals which is common for money values, you could use the following

```
//Math.round(num * 100) / 100
jQuery('#cashflow-annuel').val((Math.round((cash*12)*100) / 100) + ' € / an');
//Output ==> -6765.6
```

## [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Number/toFixed)

In your question your proposed to use `toFixed(1)`. This function will transform your number into a character chain representing a number with 1 decimal

```
jQuery('#cashflow-annuel').val((cash*12).toFixed(1) + ' € / an');
//Output ==> "-6766.0"
```